# What is meant by "omega suppression" in a lock in amplifier context?

Tags: noise, signal-detection

Can anyone explain what is meant by "Omega suppression" in lock-in amplifier discussions or specifications. I'm usually very good at web-searching, but have been unable to find anything that explains rather than mentions this term. I find it mentioned in some manuals but never explained.

Omega and 2 Omega sound like fundamental and 2nd harmonic, but ...?

**Some mentions:**

In passing only here [Setting up a Digitally Tunable Resonator using the HF2LI](https://blogs.zhinst.com/andreas/setting-up-a-digitally-tunable-resonator-using-the-hf2li/)

Many mentions here [MFLI User Manual](https://mrsec.utexas.edu/sites/default/files/ziMFLI_UserManual_58300.pdf) but meaning uncertain from context.

Comment: Have you asked Zurich Instruments?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this page](https://www.zhinst.com/ch/en/resources/principles-of-lock-in-detection), the part where they explain "*Signal Dynamics and Demodulation Bandwidth*" (search for `suppress`), they give an example of AM demodulation by comparing simple filtering with a locked-in filter. In the text, they say:

> For the second set of requirements, frequency components corresponding to the sidebands are rejected by reducing the filter bandwidth to a value smaller than fm [...]

I don't know whether this is what "omega suppression" is about, but it seems to fit the description. What's more, the link you give is for the same datasheet as [theirs](https://docs.zhinst.com/pdf/ziMFLI_UserManual.pdf) (newer, to be expected). So my guess is the device has an option for suppressing the sidebands, as described on page 59 on their datasheet (the newer one):

> - Multi-harmonic  mode  (optional,  simultaneous  measurement  up  to  four  harmonicfrequencies)
> - Arbitrary frequency mode (optional, simultaneous measurement at 4 arbitrary frequencies

I didn't read everything, just glanced, so based on these, this is my conclusion. Maybe there are others.